# How is it possible to install VMware tools on a guest, without host access?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, teamviewer, vmware-tools

I have TeamViewer access to a VMware virtual machine, which is running Ubuntu.
I would like to install VMware tools on it, but I can't, because all of the tutorials start with: Mount an image...

I have no access to the host, only to the guest.

Comment: Are these tools installed on the host or on the guest? If on the guest, then mount it as a virtual image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools` (for a guest running Ubuntu Server) or `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop` (for a guest running Ubuntu Desktop).

VMware [recommends](https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803) using `open-vm-tools` instead of the proprietary distribution.